# How to read JSON request body using Dropwizard

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard

I've been writing simple dropwizard application, and everything worked fine, untill I had to change request type. As I previously got my arguments from Header, now I have to get them from the body of a JSON request. And the saddest part is - there is no complete documentation for dropwizard or any article, that would help me. Here's my code:

```
@Path("/actors")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ActorResource {
    private final ActorDAO dao;

    public ActorResource(ActorDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @POST
    @UnitOfWork
    public Saying postActor(@HeaderParam("actorName") String name,@HeaderParam("actorBirthDate") String birthDate) {
        Actor actor = dao.create(new Actor(name,birthDate));
        return new Saying("Added : " + actor.toString());
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: This is not a dropwizard problem, but rather a jersey issue. You can create your body object with the correct annotations in code, then just have it as an argument. Jersey will automatically parse the body into the object provided. The method must accept Json for this. Alternatively, you can inject the HttpServletRequest and read the body manually.

Comment: Could you give me an example of code where Jersey automatically parse the body into object? Which annotations should i use? 
I saw HttpServletRequest method, but it's painfull

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as requested, here's a snippet demonstrating what you want to do:

```
@Path("/testPost")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource {

    @POST
    public Response logEvent(TestClass c) {
        System.out.println(c.p1);

        return Response.noContent().build();
    }

    public static class TestClass {

        @JsonProperty("p1")
        public String p1;

    }
}
```

The TestClass is my body. Jersey knows right away, that it needs to parse the body into that object.

I can then curl my API doing this:

```
curl -v  -XPOST "localhost:8085/api/testPost" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"p1":"world"}'
```

Jersey knows by the method parameter what to do, and by the Jackson Annotation how to treat the JSON.

Hope that helps,

Artur

Edit: For the more manual approach, you can:

In your post method, inject

```
@Context HttpServletRequest request
```

And from the injected request, write the body into a String for handling:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), writer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to read input stream");
        }
```

Now use any library to map that string to whatever Object you want.